# is there a way to remove the file attach icon in webchat?

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

[image: sample]

i am looking for a way to remove this icon which is highlighted in the picture.

> Additional information:
>
> using webchat 4.8
>
> implementing in an angular project.

Comment: The webchat github repository provides a sample for this: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/02.branding-styling-and-customization/f.hide-upload-button/README.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can pass in the `hideUploadButton: true` in `styleOptions`. Then pass that is to the Web Chat renderer. For a full list of `styleOptions` parameters, reference [this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/component/src/Styles/defaultStyleOptions.js) file.

```js
const styleOptions = {
  hideUploadButton: true,
}

[ ... ]

window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
  {
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine( {
      token: token
    } ),
    styleOptions: styleOptions
  document.getElementById( 'webchat' )
);
```

Hope of help!